# Everytime I open emacs with -nw my file is prepended with 0;276;0c. My screen realestate is also being cut in half

Tags: display

How can I reset the default behavior of no prepending (but still being able to use -nw) and not having the bottom half of my terminal be black space.

Having emacs test.py -nw -Q doesn't solve the issue, emacs test.py -Q doesn't result in the characters but it does produce a window that I'd rather not have.

I'm using emacs within a python jupyter shell, my version is GNU emacs 23.1.1, echo $TERM returns xterm.

As additional clarification, if I fully expand my terminal window, the emacs editor will only fill about half of the space. It isn't being filled with the "help editor" as sometimes happens.

[image: Example behavior]

Comment: Which terminal emulator you use (e.g. gnome-terminal), which emacs version and the value of your TERM variable inside the terminal will be relevant.

Comment: I'm using emacs within a python jupyter shell, my version is GNU emacs 23.1.1. How do I check my TERM variable? Thank you.

Comment: When I open my file with emacs in my XQuartz shell I don't have these issues but I have in the past not had problems using Jupyter.

Comment: You can check the value of TERM with e.g. `echo $TERM` under your terminal. Also, I don't know what "python jupyter shell" is, but it doesn't look like the name of a terminal emulator, more like the name of a shell.

Comment: Python jupyter (or ipython) is a command shell and the terminal emulator appears to be xterm. echo $TERM returns xterm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `etc/PROBLEMS` (part of emacs) has some information on this problem.

> ** Unexpected characters inserted into the buffer when you start Emacs. See e.g. http://debbugs.gnu.org/11129>
>
> This can happen when you start Emacs in -nw mode in an Xterm. For
>   example, in the *scratch* buffer, you might see something like:
>
> 0;276;0c
>
> This is more likely to happen if you are using Emacs over a slow
>   connection, and begin typing before Emacs is ready to respond.
>
> This occurs when Emacs tries to query the terminal to see what
>   capabilities it supports, and gets confused by the answer. To avoid
>   it, set xterm-extra-capabilities to a value other than 'check' (the
>   default).  See that variable's documentation (in term/xterm.el) for
>   more details.

Even if you connection is not slow, it can also happen that the value of your TERM variable doesn't match the actual capabilities of your terminal emulator — the result is still that emacs is confused.

Comment: Great thanks, since I am new to this can you tell me how to set a different value for xterm-extra-capabilities?

Comment: I think you can set it from your init file, i.e. add `(setq xterm-extra-capabilities nil)` there and see if it helps (of course, don't use `-Q` to test).

Comment: I added that to my .emacs file and the unexpected characters still occured. Here are my current file contents if I've missed something (I can't seem to be able to preserve line formatting)   :                                                 (custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t))
(setq xterm-extra-capabilities nil)

Comment: Not  sure why that happens... I hope someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty annoying, more so because this wasn't always an issue and I'm not sure what has changed.

Comment: OK so that variable did not exist in Emacs 23 (see the bug report linked to in my answer), that is an explanation. Try setting TERM to some other value before starting Emacs, e.g. vt100 (that is a bad setting but at least it should work)

Comment: So I haven't tried changing the TERM value but I thought I would pursue the slow connection issue and I closed out my session (and just did a quick update on my ipython as the issue seemed confined to that shell) and the issue seems resolved now. Thanks for the help